# NetTopologySuite ConcaveHull ends with the exception

Tags: c#, algorithm, exception, nettopologysuite, concave-hull

I use `NetTopologySuite.Algorithm.Hull.ConcaveHull.ConcaveHullByLengthRatio (Geometry geom, double lengthRatio, bool isHolesAllowed)` to build a concave hull. Sometimes the function works fine, but sometimes it falls with an exception:

```
NetTopologySuite.Triangulate.QuadEdge.LocateFailureException: Locate failed to converge (at edge: LINESTRING( 38.52788223 59.20800324999999, 38.529696464538574 59.20393475499401)).  Possible causes include invalid Subdivision topology or very close sites
         at NetTopologySuite.Triangulate.QuadEdge.QuadEdgeSubdivision.LocateFromEdge(Vertex v, QuadEdge startEdge)
         at NetTopologySuite.Triangulate.QuadEdge.LastFoundQuadEdgeLocator.Locate(Vertex v)
         at NetTopologySuite.Triangulate.IncrementalDelaunayTriangulator.InsertSite(Vertex v)
         at NetTopologySuite.Triangulate.IncrementalDelaunayTriangulator.InsertSites(ICollection`1 vertices)
         at NetTopologySuite.Triangulate.DelaunayTriangulationBuilder.Create()
         at NetTopologySuite.Triangulate.DelaunayTriangulationBuilder.GetSubdivision()
         at NetTopologySuite.Algorithm.Hull.HullTriangulation.CreateDelaunayTriangulation(Geometry geom)
         at NetTopologySuite.Algorithm.Hull.ConcaveHull.GetHull()
         at NetTopologySuite.Algorithm.Hull.ConcaveHull.ConcaveHullByLengthRatio(Geometry geom, Double lengthRatio, Boolean isHolesAllowed)
```

`lengthRatio` is 0.2, `isHolesAllowed` is true.

geom is MultiPoint containing coordinates, [for example](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LifQUIBFk7V01OkIcmRmAQizpe11lIPO/view?usp=sharing) .

I've tried to change `lengthRatio` from 0.1 to 1.0 and set `isHolesAllowed` to false - nothing changed.

If someone has faced a similar problem, please help me. What should I do to avoid such behaviour of the function?